# How do I move the weather indicator to the top-panel in gnome-shell

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel

I'm having a really annoying problem! I just can't move an extension (weather indicator) from bottom panel to top panel!! 
I would really appreciate if someone helped!

[image]

Comment: please can you link to a screenshot and add the version of ubuntu you are using to your question.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 with Gnome shell...  http://failiem.lv/u/khmcgqr

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The unity indicators do not display in the gnome-shell top-panel.  You will need to use gnome-shell extensions such as the one in the picture.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-weather
```

Logout and login and start *gnome-tweak-tool* and turn on the weather extension.

You can configure your location by finding your WOEID code from http://edg3.co.uk/snippets/weather-location-codes/

Answer (score 1):

Gnome shell treats status icons from running programs (bottom bar) differently from actual shell applets (top bar). You can get a weather extension which goes on the top bar by following this article:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/install-gnome-shell-weather-extension.html